# Config.xml is missing while creating new ios phonegap project?

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, cordova

Hi I'm new to ios and Xcode. Now I'm creating a new phonegap project in CLI. But I did not get config.xml in that project. Is my project creation is wrong ? How can I get config.xml in my project because with out config.xml how can i add new plugin features in my project?

Comment: I believe it's no longer `plugin.xml`. It is now `config.xml`.

Comment: Yeah, My fault. I mean it's config.xml